# Is there a powershell command to find a file with specific content?

Tags: powershell

So i am currently tackling a task I have been given as a challenge from my teacher, but it is safe to say I am pretty stumped. I am supposed to find a log file on a virtual machine drive which contains the specific keyword "x".

Is there a specific command I could use to search through every file for that keyword?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

`Select-String` is the cmdlet you're looking for.

```
dir *.log | select-string 'stringtofind' -simplematch
```

or

```
dir *.log | select-string 'regex pattern
```

will output matching lines.  The output is objects which points to the file, the line number, and the matching text (among other things).

Comment: is there a way to automate searching through every directory?

Comment: Sure... use the `-Recurse` switch on dir (Get-ChildItem)

Answer (score 0):

There is no command I am aware of that will directly search for a file with a specific content. You will have to open each file, and use regex to find the string. You would use `Get-Childitem` to get a list of each file in the log directory, and then `foreach` item you would `Get-Content` and then check if that content has the string you are looking for.

However, if you wanted an A+, you could run the task of searching each file as a job or a runspace to check each file in parallel/new thread, which would greatly increase the speed of sorting through many files, but that is a more advanced technique.

Part of the lesson is learning how to code this, so I am omitting the code, and giving you the key commands you should be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to do something like:

Get-Childitem -Path path\to\search -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-String -pattern "jonathan.williams" | group path | select name

Update:

You can change it to

Get-Childitem -Path path\to\search -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-String "jonathan.williams"

to get the line number along with the file as well